# Как вывести нужный элемент из массива

Tags: php, phpstorm

Имеется два файла - в одном находится массив с вопросами, в другом файле должен выводиться нужный вопрос. В боте пользователь нажимает на вопросы в кнопках, сам бот должен эти вопросы выводить в отдельный чат

Собственно вот код из файла с вопросами

```
$asking_questions = [

'contact_HowToDownload_v1' => [
    'asking_text' => 'Как загружать с аккаунтов?'
],

'contact_IsNotDownloading_v1' => [
    'asking_text' => 'Не загружаются медиа'
],

'contact_HowMuchIsLoaded_v1' => [
    'asking_text' => 'Сколько загружаются видео?'
] ]
```

Вот из исполняемого файла

```
if ($prefix === 'contact') { // прислать сообщение в группу
        if ($asking_questions[$callback_data]) {
            $asking = $asking_questions[$callback_data];
            $post = [
                'chat_id' => GROUP_ID,
                'text' => '‍ Пользователь ' . '<a href="tg://user?id=' . $user_id . '">id' . $user_id . '</a>' . ' обратился с вопросом: ' . $asking_questions['asking_text'],
                'parse_mode' => 'html'
            ];
            telegram('sendMessage', $post);
        } }
```

Бот в чате выводит только сообщение без самого вопроса:
[image: бот не выводит вопросы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, оказывается вместо `$asking_questions['asking_text']` нужно было использовать `$asking['asking_text']`